# Can't pass variable into ajax url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I'm basically trying to delete an item in mongodb.  But I just can't seem to pass the id into the url in the ajax call.  Here's my code:

```js
$(".delete-item").on('click', function(e, id) {
              var deleteName = $('p.nameLink').text();

// Get ID first

             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/items",
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .done(function(result) { 

            // searches mongodb for the clicked name and saves the result in the var     
             var newResult = $.grep(result, function(e){ return e.name === deleteName; });


              var id = newResult[0]._id;
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(error);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            });

// Then delete

            console.log("ID to DELETE:", id);  // I can see id

            function itemDelete(id) {

             $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: '/items/' + id,
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .done(function(result) {

           console.log("ID to DELETE:", id); // Can't see the id

            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(error);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            });

            }

            itemDelete(id); // pass the id to the function 
         });
```

I'm just learning at the moment, so I could be going about this the wrong way.  If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it.

The error message is:

DELETE https://www.someplace.com/items/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Try to use `type:'POST'` instead `type:DELETE''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ajax calls are asynchronous, you should call *itemDelete(id)* from inside the first *.done* callback.
Try moving

```
itemDelete(id);
```

just after

```
var id = newResult[0]._id;
```

This way you will execute your second ajax call only after the first has terminated, and the *id* variable will be defined.

After the change your code should look like this:

```
$(".delete-item").on('click', function(e, id) {
    var deleteName = $('p.nameLink').text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/items",
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(result) { 
        var newResult = $.grep(result, function(e){ 
            return e.name === deleteName; 
        });

        var id = newResult[0]._id;
        itemDelete(id);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(error);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });

    function itemDelete(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/items/' + id,
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .done(function(result) {


            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(error);
                console.log(errorThrown);
        });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work for you.

$(".delete-item").on('click', function(e, id) {
              var deleteName = $('p.nameLink').text();

// Get ID first

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/items",
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .done(function(result) { 

        // searches mongodb for the clicked name and saves the result in the var     
         var newResult = $.grep(result, function(e){ return e.name === deleteName; });


          var id = newResult[0]._id;
          itemDelete(id); // pass the id to the function 
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(error);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });



        console.log("ID to DELETE:", id);  // I can see id

        function itemDelete(id) {

         $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/items/' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .done(function(result) {

       console.log("ID to DELETE:", id); // Can't see the id

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(error);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });

        }


     });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined` in `https://www.someplace.com/items/undefined` suggests that the id is undefined. Note that the get and delete requests happen asynchronously, so `id` is not guaranteed to be set when you make the delete request, since it depends on when the request completes. In other words, try deleting *after* you get the id. This would require you to make the DELETE request in the success callback of the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Please try This one

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            dataType : 'html',
            url: 'your_url',
            data:{variablname:id,type:'DELETE'}
            dataType: 'json',
        })
```

In your url page or action get the value as its type is get so the data type will be GET

```
 if(isset($_GET['variablename'],$_GET['type'])){
     if($_GET['type']=='DELETE')
       delete record from database where id= $_GET['variablename']
}
```

I hope it will help you Thanks